Has Biden ever explained why he is running for president (2024)?
There've been several poll that suggest that Democrats would rather the party nominate someone else for president, e.g. this or this. There've also been indications that Americans as a whole would rather someone else (since most of them don't want a Trump vs. Biden rematch), Biden's approval ratings are fairly low, and quite a few people have expressed concerns about his age.
Given that, has Biden ever explained why he is running? I'm looking for answers where Biden explains why he thinks he's a better president than other potential Democratic candidates (as opposed to Trump), or where he e.g. says there's X thing he wants to do that he hasn't done yet, etc. Wiki's article on Biden's 2024 campaign does not seem to have any such statements (as of time of writing).

Does the fact that someone who thought they would make a good president still thinks that really need much of an explanation?

@Obie2.0 especially as the last time they checked, a majority of people agreed with that assessment

@Caleth do they? From what I've seen, Biden's approval rating is rather low.

I meant the 2020 election

He has made vague speeches - you could watch his actual announcement on April 25, 2023. I don't know whether you would judge his repetition of "let's finish the job" offers a particularly clear statement of why he's running. How precise do you want? (As to why he's better than the alternatives, there seems to be a total lack of alternatives - with nobody running against him why would he have to explain why he's better?)

Biden's approval rating can be misleading, as he was always the centrist compromise in the face of Trumpism. He was the candidate everyone could live with that few particularly cared for. His disapproval comes from both sides because he's not notably liberal.

@StuartF well has he ever addressed the people who think he should step aside and let someone else run? If so, what did he say?

Would we ask this question of any other president who is eligible to run for a second term? It is generally a given that a president who is eligible for reelection that they will run for another term. Can't the same be said about Trump as well that a majority of people would prefer someone else and would rather have something besides a Biden/Trump rematch this year?

Apparently, to give Trump the best chance of winning election. That's why we saw him wearing a maga hat in September.

In Biden's campaign launch video (which is narrated by Biden himself) he lists various things he is for and against

Freedom and fairness ("to make sure everyone has a shot at making it")
Protecting Social Security
Ending tax cuts for the wealthy
Prevent dictating healthcare (shown with pro-abortion protests to emphasize his pro-abortion stance)
Prevent book banning
Not telling people who they can love (shows a picture of the man who filed the case that made gay marriage legal)
Making it easier to vote

He then says this (around 1:05 in the video)

When I ran for president four years ago, I said we were in a battle for the soul of America. And we still are.

A recent speech by Biden also mentioned tax increases on the rich

We’re just getting started. In a second term, we want to keep it going to level the playing field by making the wealthy begin to pay their fair tax. (Applause.) It ain’t even close.
I said I’d not increase the tax of anybody making less than $400,000 a year. Well, guess who — how much — guess how much the average federal tax rate is for a billionaire? We’ve got a thousand of them. 8.3 percent. 8.3 percent. It’s outrageous. If the billionaires only had to pay 25 percent, it would raise 40 — $400 billion. We’d be able to do everything we’re doing now and still reduce the debt.

Passing the Democrat's Voting rights act and stopping "book banning"

Folks, reelect Kamala and me and a Democratic Congress, and I will sign the John Lewis Voting Right Act and the Freedom to Vote Act tomorrow — (applause) — and we will make Roe v. Wade the law of the land again. (Applause.) It’s within our power to do this.
MAGA extremists ban books. Did you ever think — if you’re anybody over 30 years old — you’d go through a period where we’re banning books in America? They’re trying to erase Black history. We’re going to write Black history, because it’s American history. (Applause.) It’s American history.

And, finally, stopping Donald Trump

The stakes in this election couldn’t be higher. What’s at stake is nothing less than the fundamental ideal of America — it defines America: that we’re all created equal, endowed by our Creator with certain inalienable rights, and should be treated that way throughout our lives. We’ve never lived up to it, but we’ve never, ever before completely walked away from it, either.
And I’ll be damned if I’m going to let Donald Trump be the reason we stopped being America. (Applause.)


FWTW, at one point late last year he said it was mainly because Trump was running, but then sort-of 'backtracked' answering a hypothetical.

“If Trump wasn’t running, I’m not sure I’d be running,” he told donors gathered at a fundraiser in Weston, Massachusetts, according to The New York Times. “But we cannot let him win.”
[...] Hours after making the comments in Massachusetts, Biden tried to walk them back while speaking to reporters during his return to the White House. “I expect so,” he replied when asked if he would still seek reelection absent a rematch with Trump. “But look, he is running, and I have to run.”  Biden was then asked whether he would consider exiting the race if Trump were to drop out, to which he responded, “No, not now.”

Related to that, a couple of months earlier, he was quoted:

“I’m running because democracy is at stake," Biden said. "And let there be no question, Donald Trump and his MAGA Republicans are determined to destroy American democracy. And I will always defend, protect and fight for our democracy.”


Does this mean Biden perceives himself as the candidate most likely to defeat Trump?

It means he claims his absence would make a Trump victory more likely. A subtly but importantly different claim.

@Allure Isn't that how every candidate sees themselves? As the ones who can win the election? Otherwise why would they be running in the first place?

@Allure: AFAIK he hasn't put it quite in those terms, but he did say at least he's the only one who did beat Trump. (Even if that's obvious.)

IIRC, this was also the reason he gave in 2020. That doesn't mean that's the real reason, but since Trump is running this time too, the story is consistent.

@JoeW Trump is largely believed to have run the first time not because he thought he could win but because it was an opportunity for lots of press to help his business endeavors.  And third party candidates almost never suffer under the delusion that they could actually win.  What they want is to promote a message and get one or both main parties to adjust their platforms and rhetoric to incorporate achieving one of the third party's goals.  And in the days of smoke filled back rooms the presidential candidate was selected largely for being predictable and controllable.

@zibadawatimmy sure there are exceptions to every rule, but that really only applies to the primary and not the general elections.

In a campaign speech last week  Biden mentioned that  for  all that he did do in office he has not yet  raised taxes on those who are earning over $400,000. That is something he needs a second term to do .

We’re just getting started. In a second term, we want to keep it going to level the playing field by making the wealthy begin to pay their fair tax. (Applause.) It ain’t even close.

https://www.whitehouse.gov/briefing-room/speeches-remarks/2024/05/29/remarks-by-president-biden-and-vice-president-harris-at-a-campaign-event-philadelphia-pa/

Now that the election campaign and election are over, in hindsight, we can see the bigger picture of why Biden was running for President in 2024 (despite his poor health) - he and his party were clearly trying to implement ex-President Gerald Ford's political vision that it would be easier for a woman vice-president to takeover the presidency directly from another President, than to win it electorally - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=epWYJ_SY8uU&t=48s
In 1989, Gerald Ford said that the way he expected a woman politician to breakthrough the political barrier of becoming the President of the US was by first becoming a vice-president. And then, assuming the office the President of the USA when the President died in office. This, in his view, would allow the American public to see a woman politician in the Presidential office, and normalise it in the public eyes and thus allow any aspiring American woman politician to get elected as the President of the United States, in the future.
In hindsight, now, this is evident as the Biden / Democratic plan:

Biden qualified for the Democratic primary while Kamala Harris didn't.
Biden made her a running mate as the vice-president candidate.
He wasn't in good enough health to even campaign but thought he could.
Ultimately, he had to quit in the middle of the campaign due to his poor health and the Democrats were unexpectedly forced to make Kamala Harris as the Presidential candidate.
Thus, it is evident that even if Biden had been elected President of the USA, he would have quit in the mid-term (very possibly in the first year itself). This would automatically have made Kamala Harris as the first woman President of the US (for the remaining term).


Is there any evidence Biden was explicitly planning this?

@Allure Specific statements - not that I am aware of. But it has been clear for sometime that the Democrats have been wanting to give people of colour and woman more political representation to counter the criticism that American politics isn't systemically preferring and promoting white, Christian, male politicians. They were able to provide a successful platform to Barack Obama to be the first black President of the US. Now they are trying to do the same amongst the women politicians - first with Hillary Clinton and, now with Kamala Harris. In hindsight, their intent is now more obvious.

This sounds like a conspiracy theory to me.

First, Kamala has already been acting President. Second, you're presuming a complicated plan to get Kamala as President that first requires Biden to be reelected is somehow more likely true than Biden actually wanting to be president? Based on nothing more than conspiracy-mongering?

@Barmar I am really confused - what exactly is the "conspiracy" that all of you think I am spouting? What I have described is a political strategy by party leaders (including Biden) to increase representation of minorities and make American democracy more representative! It is a fact that the world's oldest democracy has only had white, male, Christians as President, until Obama was elected. Obviously this highlights a problem that the Democrats want to address, especially since this has been now weaponised against America by its rivals.

@bharring What exactly is the "conspiracy-mongering" that you think I am doing with this answer? What I have outlined is a political strategy by a party to increase minority representation. Acting President is not the same as being the President; there have been many acting Presidents in the history of the US - do you remember any of them or anything impactful done by them? The fact that Biden knew he was not healthy enough to assume office, is clear now. Do you dispute that? If not, then it is clear that he (and his party) planned for Kamala Harris to take over when he quit in office.

A secret plan by “party leaders” that would be seen as an abuse of the system if it leaked out is, indeed, a conspiracy. And, a presumed conspiracy for which you have no evidence except pure speculation is, indeed, a conspiracy theory. So this choice of words is spot on.

@EmilJeřábek What "abuse" of system? The vice-president taking charge when the President dies or quits is precisely how the system is designed to work! That is exactly what Gerald Ford also points out, publicly (and he did it 30+ years ago). All of you are acting as if political parties enter into elections without any strategy on how to win or further their politics. If all of you really believe that a political strategy to increase minority representation by the Democrats / Biden is a "conspiracy", then you don't understand either democracy or politics. (Or you guys are just trolling me).

The system is designed to work like this when, as you say, the President dies. Or in similar extraordinary circumstances that prevent them from continuing to serve in the office. It is a fundamental principle of democratic elections that people vote for the candidates that then take the office, barring unforseen extraordinary circumstances. If someone intentionally runs for an office only so that he can quit and pass the office to someone else, this is an abuse of the system.

If this was indeed the plan, the fact that they needed to keep it secret indicates that they knew it was dubious. Contrast this with the Federalist Society's plan to move SCOTUS to the right, and Project 2025 -- these plans to reshape the federal government are out in the open.

@EmilJeřábek as you say, the President dies - Or impeached or resigns or is incapacitated in some manner. If someone intentionally runs for an office only so that he can quit and pass the office to someone else, this is an abuse of the system. No, it isn't because in the US a President stands for elections with a running mate (the vice-presidential candidate) - they are a "package deal". And the Electorate scrutinises both the candidates. Winning an election, ensuring a proper successor and then passing on the baton is an old and tried and tested strategy.

@Barmar the fact that they needed to keep it secret indicates that they knew it was dubious. - I don't think dubious is the right word. And it isn't exactly a secret when you consider that Gerald Ford outlined this publicly 30+ years ago. It is clear that the US society has a preference for white, male, christian politicians. (Obama slightly changed that but is still an outlier). It is clear that there is still some resistance to the idea of Americans of different ethnicity, religion gender etc.  occupying the Presidential post. How do you change that? One way is to increase representation.

@sfxedit Racism and sexism are hardly secrets, the secret was the (claimed) conspiracy to re-elect Biden so that he can then allow Harris to take his place.

Downvoting this because there's no evidence provided that Biden was expecting to step down during his second term.  I do think that he likely would have had to do so, but there's a big difference between "this seems likely to happen" and "this was intentionally done".

@Bobson Hence, hindsight - that Biden stepped down midway in campaign proves that he knew he wasn't healthy enough to continue as President and planned to eventually step down mid term (if he won the Presidency).

@sfxedit Or it proves that he realized that he'd blown the election and the Dem's only hope was to let someone else try.  Or at least he was convinced of that by other party leaders.  I'd actually say that he only held on for so long because he did think he was healthy enough to continue as President with no plans to step down.  There's just as much evidence for that as for the reverse.

@Bobson He blew the campaign because of his health - after it became obvious to the public during the debate debacle. So it must have been already obvious to party strategist long before itself that his health was failing. Yet, they didn't do anything to dissuade him till the public became aware of it.

@sfxedit - Or they tried and couldn't convince him until the public became aware and he saw what it was doing to the polls.  It's very possible that he still thinks he is healthy enough to have been President for an entire second term.  That doesn't mean he objectively is (he clearly isn't), but it's common for elderly people to not be willing to admit (or even able to see) how bad off they've gotten.  And if he doesn't/can't see his decline and still thinks he'd be capable, then he clearly wouldn't be planning on stepping aside to let Harris become President.

@sfxedit - I'm not saying that I'm right and you're wrong about what happened behind the scenes, just that there are many possibilities for what happened, and stating definitively that he intended to step down midterm is unsupported by any evidence.  What there is can be interpreted in multiple ways, so it can't be used to prove one interpretation over another.  When the behind-the-scenes books come out in a few years, we'll have a better picture of how it all played out.

@Bobson I can agree with you on that. One thing is sure though - the Democrats do want to make sure that the first woman President is from their party and are giving more opportunities to women candidates. It is understandable because some dysfunction indeed has set in American politics where it is difficult for some people to find political representation easily. India, Bangladesh, Pakistan and even many European countries have already had woman leaders in the highest political post whereas the US electorate apparently still hasn't matured enough to accept this after 200+ years of democracy.
